# How to compare two columns using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

BACKGROUND:
I have two columns: 'address' and 'raw_data'. The dataset looks like this:
[this is just a sample I made up, the original dataset is over 6m rows and in a different language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GquSr.png)

Problem:
I need to find all the data where the 'address' and 'raw_data' are not matched meaning there were some sorta of mistakes were made when logging in the data from 'address' to 'raw_data.

I'm fairly new to Pandas. My plan is separate the 'raw_data' column by comma, then compare the newly produced columns with the original 'address' column (to see if the 'address' column has those info, if not, that means there is a mistake?).

Like I said, I'm new to pandas and this is what I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['address', 'raw_data']
df=pd.read_csv('address.csv', usecols=columns)
df = pd.concat([df['address'], df['raw_data'].str.split(',', expand=True)], axis=1)
```

Now the new columns has info like this: "CITY":"ATLANTA". I want to the columns to just have ATLANTA without all the the colons and 'CITY' in order to compare the info with 'address' column.
How should I go on about it?

Also, at this point of my pandas learning experience, I do not yet know how to compare two columns. Could someone help a newbie out please? Thanks a lot!

PS: by comparison of two columns I meant to check whether one column has the characters in the second column, not to check whether the two columns are equal. Just want to point that out.

Comment: Please add sample data in text format.

Answer (score 5):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 2], [3, 6],[1,1]], columns = ["col1", "col2"])
comparison_column = np.where(df["col1"] == df["col2"], True, False)
df["equal"] = comparison_column



col1  col2  equal
 2     2   True
 3     6  False
 1     1   True
```

Comment: You can use simply `df["col1"] == df["col2"]`. Here `np.where` is not required.

Comment: off-course we can use,  in case if we want more specific flag instead of bool(True/False)  then np.where() will help us more.

Answer (score 1):

I will use this data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
j = {"address":"foo","b": "bar"}
j2 = {"address":"foo2","b": "bar2"}
values = [["foo", j], ["bar", j2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=values, columns=["address", "raw_data"])
df
    address raw_data
0   foo {'address': 'foo', 'b': 'bar'}
1   bar {'address': 'foo2', 'b': 'bar2'}
```

I will separate columns from raw_data (with **.values.tolist()**) in another df (df2):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['raw_data'].values.tolist())
df2
    address b
0   foo bar
1   foo2    bar2
```

To compare you use:

```
  df.address == df2.address
0     True
1    False
```

If you need save this in the original df you can add a column:

```
df["result"] = df.address == df2.address
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate them from `,` by just treating them as a `dict`. You can map custom functions to columns with [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function. In this case you have define a function that accesses to keys of dictionary and extracts values.

```
df['address_raw'] = df['raw_data'].apply(lambda x: x['address'])
df['city_raw'] = df['raw_data'].apply(lambda x: x['CITY'])
df['addrline2_raw'] = df['raw_data'].apply(lambda x: x['ADDR_LINE_2'])
df['addrline3_raw'] = df['raw_data'].apply(lambda x: x['ADDR_LINE_3'])
df['utmnorthing_raw'] = df['raw_data'].apply(lambda x: x['UTM_NORTHING'])
```

These lines will create columns of each field in the dict and then you can just compare the ones like:

```
df['address'] == df['address_raw']
```